# Web View loading html file issue

Tags: android, html, text, webview, loading

I am loading content of html from assets folder in the webview, but its display white flash means appearing half text of html for few seconds then whole contents loading.

I tried a lot but not solved.My code is below:-

```
webIntroductionText = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webIntroductionText);
webIntroductionText.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);

webIntroductionText.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webIntroductionText.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/webpages/how-to-use.html");


webIntroductionText.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE); 
webIntroductionText.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
```

If anyone have solution about this.Thanks in advance....

Comment: what ur html page contains?

Comment: thanks for reply @Monika, simple content with css applied also.there is no image.

Comment: try this once :android:hardwareAccelerated="false"

Comment: issue appear in Nexus 7, but working fine in samsung tab2.

Comment: try above code in xml

Comment: this tag already declared in AndoridManifest file.

Comment: I have three webview and loading the different on particular button click event.Also disabling and enabling the webview.

Comment: so all 3 webview flicker?

Comment: Sorry,I am not understanding.can you please explain?

Comment: i mean that white part u r saying abt is in all 3 webview?

Comment: Thanks!! Issue solved but one more issue occured means webview scrolling long.If content not available then also scrolling.

Comment: try this  Webview.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);
Webview.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);

Comment: Thanks a lot @Monika, You saved my lot of time.Great!!

Comment: ya...sure. You can post answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You May try this code for avoiding white flash :

```
android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
```

& For avoiding scrolling of webview you can use :

```
Webview.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);
Webview.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);
```